# NullPointerException when I changed all my methods to static

Tags: eclipse, selenium, static, webdriver, pom.xml

Using Selenium w Java and Test NG (POM format) Switched everything from not static to static and changed everything accordingly, getting NullPointerException. It worked when everything was not static, but making everything static requires less code so I'd prefer to have it that way.

Here is my code.. while trying to paste my code for some reason it did not recognize the import statements as code so I just did not include them, but rest assured everything has been imported that is needed! :)

```
Package pages;
public class locationPage {

WebDriver driver;
static @FindBy (id="btn_bogota") WebElement chooseBogota;
static @FindBy (id="btn_medellin") WebElement chooseMedellin;
static @FindBy (xpath="//title") WebElement pageTitle;


public locationPage (WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public static void chooseLocation (String location) {
    if (location.equals("Bogota"))
    {
        chooseBogota.click();
    }
    else if (location.equals("Medellin")){
        chooseMedellin.click();
    }   
}
}
```

---

```
Package testcases;
public class selectLocation {

 WebDriver driver;

 @BeforeClass
public void setup() throws InterruptedException{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://dev01.juanregala.com.co/");    
  //Generating Alert Using Javascript Executor
    JavascriptExecutor javascript = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    javascript.executeScript("alert('Select Location');");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}

@AfterTest
public void quit(){
    driver.quit();
}

 @Test (priority=0)
 public void location(){
    locationPage.chooseLocation("Medellin");
 }
}
```

It keeps giving me a NullPointerException referring to

```
            chooseMedellin.click();
```

and

```
        locationPage.chooseLocation("Medellin");
```

I am not really sure how else to describe my issue :( Please help!

Comment: Also ... I think you are probably not understanding the use of the `@AfterTest` annotation in TestNG. That does *not* run after each test method but rather after all the tests in the `<test>` node of that particular TestNG suite. I think you actually want the `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` annotations which run before and after (respectively) **each** `@Test` method. See TestNG documentation : http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Yeah I changed it right after I posted the question! Thank you though for recognizing that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NullPointerException because the fields are not initialized. You can't use a page object in this way. Even if you could, you probably wouldn't want to since a page object is tied to a particular web driver and that would mean you could never use the same page object among multiple tests and run them in parallel.

Basically, the `PageFactory` only works on object `instances`. It won't initialize static fields and, even if it did, you are only calling the page factory from the constructor of your page and that is never being called since you only call a static method on that class.

You need to create an instance of the page object and then pass it to the `PageFactory` along with the driver that will be running the page object.

Simple example:

```
public class FooTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private FooPage page;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FooPage.class);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        try {
            driver.quit();
        } catch ( Exception ignore ) { }
        driver = null;
        page = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {

    }
}

public class FooPage {
    @FindBy(id="foo")
    private WebElement fooElement;

    public void clickFoo() {
        fooElement.click();
    }
}
```

Note the line:

```
page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FooPage.class);
```

That method will actually call the default construct of `FooPage`. You can also instantiate the object yourself and pass it to the page factory like this:

```
page = new FooPage();
PageFactory.initElements(driver, page);
```

Comment: "You need to create an instance of the page object and then pass it to the PageFactory along with the driver that will be running the page object." -- could you please write a sample piece of code that would do this? I am a bit confused :/

Comment: @daniyalmistry I edited my answer to add an example sample code. Sorry for the amount of time it took ... had a busy day :-)